# CoreBluetooth - get all devices connected to Bluetooth peripheral

Tags: ios7, core-location, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

Is there a way how to get list of all devices connected to the Bluetooth peripheral?
I want to connect to iBeacon and check if another iPhone is connected to it.

Comment: You can implement your own registry mechanism and offer it in custom services and characteristics. But as @barbazoo mentioned, the iBeacon is not connected.

Answer (score 4):

No, two reasons why not:

1. iBeacons are not connected to the iOS device, iBeacons are broadcast only and no back communication exist from the phone to the beacon.
2. Knowing details of other BT 4.0 Centrals connected to a Peripheral are not in line with the the privacy features of Bluetooth 4.0. iOS and other Centrals are are using resolvable private addresses, in order to avoid situation like you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

@barbazoo is correct that you cannot do exactly what you are asking because iBeacons only transmit data -- they have no idea what devices see them.

You can accomplish something similar, however, if you have an app running on each of the iOS devices you mention, and you have a server where you can build a web service.  The web service would expose two methods:

```
reportIBeaconVisible(iBeaconProximityUUID, iBeaconMajor, iBeaconMinor, myPhoneAdvertisingId)
queryVisiblePhones(iBeaconProximityUUID, iBeaconMajor, iBeaconMinor)
```

The app would report each iBeacon it sees using the first method, passing the iBeacon's identifiers, along with the phone's advertising identifier to the server.

The app could then use the second method to ask the server what other phones have seen the exact same iBeacon, which would return a list of phone advertising identifiers.

You'd have to have logic on the phone to only report data to the server at a reasonable frequency.  You'd also need code on the server to automatically delete phone records in the list if the phones haven't reported seeing a beacon in a certain time interval.